# Remove top row from a CSV file in PHP.

Tags: php, csv

Just trying to remove the first line from a CSV in php. Can't use str_replace as the content varies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How you're trying to do ? can you show to us the code ?

You can do something like:

```
$i = 0;
while(fgetcsv() !== false) {
 if ($i == 0) 
   continue;

 // your code here ...
 ++ $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through your rows, discard the first one.

```
$file       = fopen($csv_file,"r")
$junk_row   = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");
$row[0]     = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");
$row[1]     = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");
```

This is only an example, to store the rest of the rows obviously use a loop.